# Does the largest free group exists(as a "proper group")?

Tags: category-theory, free-groups

Can I define a group $F$ that is free on the proper class $S$ of all sets? If this construction were possible, F would presumably be the largest free group in the sense that every other free group would be embedded in it.

If it isn't possible to construct the largest free group, can I construct a free group that is maximal, in the sense that it can not be embedded in any other free group? Notice that if we order the class $\mathcal{F}$ of all free groups with the order $F \leq F^\prime$ iff there exists an embedding $F \rightarrow F^\prime$, then every chain in $\mathcal{F}$ will have an upper bound, whereby we can abuse Zorn's Lemma to get a maximal element.

I know such a group will not exist in Zermelo-Fraenkel Set Theory, hence, for lack of a better word I called this group a "proper group". Nevertheless, is there a alternative to Zermelo-Fraenkel in which this large group I am trying to construct exists? If so, how can I construct it?

Comment: No. by definition, a group is a set.

Comment: Do you have a use in mind for a construction like this? Zorn's lemma doesn't apply to your situation because the collection of all free groups, even up to isomorphism, is not a set. Every free group embeds nontrivially and canonically into the free group on its own underlying set.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: yes, I have use for this construction because it may have a bearing on some of my thoughts about the foundation of mathematics.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: Indeed, Zorn's Lemma doesn't apply to my situation. For that reason I called my use of Zorn's Lemma an abuse.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: my construction doesn't make sense in Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory. But can I make sense of it by changing the underlying logic(e.g. from classical to intuitionistic), or by considering a set theory with different axioms?

Comment: You could fix some large cardinal $\kappa$ and consider the free group $F(\kappa)$ on $\kappa$. Then all sets in $V_\kappa$ (which is a model of ZFC) will have there free group embedded in $F(\kappa)$. Of course $F(\kappa)$ doesn't live in $V_\kappa$. If you want this 'big free group' to 'live in the same universe' then that is simply not possible (in any reasonable foundation I can think of), as per Qiaochu's answer.